# Page centred in ie 6

Tags: css

This is starting to give me a headache, so thought I would ask for anyones input and hopefully save my eye-balls the on-going pain.

We have created a website, mainly using x-Cart, the whole site should be centred which works fine on every browser apart form that old favourite ie6.

I have looked over and over the CSS while also double checking the encoding and charset...

Any help on this welcome:

http://www.monityre.com/?shopkey=123456

Comment: Try using the `<center>` tag as a container for the main div, don't have ie6 and couldn't test..

Comment: Why do you have 2 page-container DIVs?

Comment: @Catalin Yea, try using HTML tags that have been deprecated for 10 years :)

Comment: i guess the weird way you handle the header messes things up

Comment: Thanks all, Will try the <center> tags, but wanted to keep away from them really. As for the two 2 page containers, I can't remember now, but believe there was a great reason at the time!

Comment: @Šime Vidas Yea, when using a browser that has been deprecated for 10 years :)

Comment: @jimbo I was being sarcastic.

Comment: I'd also try adding text-align:center; to the body... but that might get inherited in all other elements...

Comment: @Šime Vidas I guessed that... if it works though it will rule out a few other options

Comment: @catalin, well that centred the page, but caused more problems

Comment: @jimbo The XML declaration is causing this problem. Check out my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the reason why it doesn't work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
```

The XML declaration is triggering quirks mode in IE6. Just remove it, and it'll work.

Comment: And switch to UTF-8 (since that is the default for XML documents without an XML prolog). There is no reason to use ISO-8859-1 today, it is pure legacy with no benefits of UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting text-align:center; to the body style, and text-align:left; in div "page-container".

Answer (score 0):

Your page doesn't pass W3C validation for some reason (even IETester's Debug Bar sees something wrong with that piece of code).

Also, try removing "position:relative" from the first div.

Also, is there a reason why the menu goes after the content in your HTML, and that the menu is positioned absolute?